# Javascript calling a function inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to call a function inside for loop. I have managed to write a closure function. But its not working for me. Please help fix this issue. Your help is much appreciated.

```
for(var i = 0; i < pointsData.length; i++){
    (function(foo){
        routeId = pointsData[i]._id;
        colorId = pointsData[foo].route_color;
        console.log('color start', colorId);
        $.post('commands.php',{command: 'get-route-coords',id: pointsData[foo]._id}
            ,function(data){              
                MYMAP.setAllRoutes(last, coordinates, pointsData[foo].route_color);
            });                         
    }(i));
}
MYMAP.setAllRoutes = function(center,flightPlanCoordinates,colorId) {
    console.log('color ids', colorId);
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Your question needs more detail. Are there errors?

Comment: You're using both 'foo' (what a clear name !) and 'i' inside your function. You are not declaring 'routeId', 'colorId' as vars, so they are globals... but anyway you forgot to use them right after. You're near a one error per line ratio => Either you need to sleep, or to learn more about Javascript ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run the code inside your loop like below. What is the reason of the requirement?

```
for(var i = 0; i < pointsData.length; i++){ 
    routeId = pointsData[i]._id;
    colorId = pointsData[foo].route_color;
    console.log('color start', colorId);
    $.post('commands.php',{command: 'get-route-coords',id: pointsData[foo]._id} ,function(data){              
        MYMAP.setAllRoutes(last, coordinates, pointsData[foo].route_color);
    });  
}

MYMAP.setAllRoutes = function(center,flightPlanCoordinates,colorId) {
    console.log('color ids', colorId);
}
```